# How to check for a specific word in a textbox

Tags: javascript, css, html

I can't figure out the way to check for a specific word in a textbox/area.

Here is my code.

Javascript

```
function showConfirmationDialog() {
  var textarea = document.getElementById('Box');
  alert(textarea.value);
}

function TextChecker() {
  var word = 'foo';
  var textarea = textarea.value;
  if (textarea.indexOf(word) != -1) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're working on an environment where ES2016 is available, I'd recommend using `includes()`. It is a native Array method, which also means it is available for strings.

```js
const toBeFound = 'test string'
const toBeTested = 'this is an string where test string is present'

console.log(toBeTested.includes(toBeFound))
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is use JavaScript's toLowerCase() function and check the contents of the text box.

Be aware that this will not work if someone puts a random character in the middle of the word.

HTML:

```
<textarea id="myText">This is a textbox</textarea>
<textarea id="myText2">This is a text.box</textarea>
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('myText').value.toLowerCase().includes("textbox"); // this will return TRUE
document.getElementById('myText2').value.toLowerCase().includes("textbox"); // this will return FALSE
```